# Can I call a function of a shell script from another shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 shell scripts.

The second shell script contains following functions
*second.sh*

```
func1 
func2
```

The first.sh will call the second shell script with some parameters and
 will call func1 and func2 with some other parameters specific to that function.

Here is the example of what I am talking about

second.sh

```
val1=`echo $1`
val2=`echo $2`

function func1 {

fun=`echo $1`
book=`echo $2`

}

function func2 {

fun2=`echo $1`
book2=`echo $2`


}
```

first.sh

```
second.sh cricket football

func1 love horror
func2 ball mystery
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `v=$(echo $1)` is completely redundant.  Just write `fun2=$1`.  The only difference is that the `$()` (or backticks) will remove trailing newlines.

Comment: Since there's nothing special about calling a function from a shell script as opposed to the command line, this question can be reduced down to "How to call a bash function?"

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Refactor your `second.sh` script like this:

```
func1 {
   fun="$1"
   book="$2"
   printf "func=%s,book=%s\n" "$fun" "$book"
}

func2 {
   fun2="$1"
   book2="$2"
   printf "func2=%s,book2=%s\n" "$fun2" "$book2"
}
```

And then call these functions from script `first.sh` like this:

```
source ./second.sh
func1 love horror
func2 ball mystery
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
func=love,book=horror
func2=ball,book2=mystery
```

Comment: To avoid unintentional side effects, beware that the `source` command will actually run the script passed as argument.

Comment: @dvlcube it would be better if you could suggest an alternative.

Comment: This answer is clear and good.  Importantly, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42101141/852196 describes a problem some people might run into and provides an elegant generalized solution.

Comment: @Alpha2k I'm not really sure there is an alternative. the idea is "be careful what you're putting into the file you source"

Comment: This doesn't work: `source: not found`.

Comment: What she’ll are you using?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822868/6281925) might solve your issue.

Answer (score 94):

You can't directly call a function in another shell script.

You can move your function definitions into a separate file and then load them into your script using the `.` command, like this:

```
. /path/to/functions.sh
```

This will interpret `functions.sh` as if it's content were actually present in your file at this point.  This is a common mechanism for implementing shared libraries of shell functions.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the accepted answer, since `.` is an alias for `source` ?

Comment: Well, I answered first, so technically the accepted answer is the same as this one :). Also, while `source` is an alias for `.` in many shells, that isn't always the case.  For example, the `dash` package on Debian, which provides `/bin/sh`, does not have a `source` command.

Comment: `source` command didn't work in Ubuntu @ajsharma. Reference: [source command not found in sh shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell)

Comment: so weird that this comment is not upvoted as the highest? This is correct #!/bin/sh syntax and the other will work only in bash.

Answer (score 67):

### The problem

The currenly accepted answer works only under important condition. Given...

**`/foo/bar/first.sh`:**

```
function func1 {  
   echo "Hello $1"
}
```

and

**`/foo/bar/second.sh`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./first.sh
func1 World
```

this works only if the `first.sh` is executed from within the same directory where the `first.sh` is located. Ie. if the current working path of shell is `/foo`, the attempt to run command

```
cd /foo
./bar/second.sh
```

prints error:

```
/foo/bar/second.sh: line 4: func1: command not found
```

That's because the `source ./first.sh` is relative to current working path, not the path of the script. Hence one solution might be to utilize subshell and run

```
(cd /foo/bar; ./second.sh)
```

### More generic solution

Given...

**`/foo/bar/first.sh`:**

```
function func1 {  
   echo "Hello $1"
}
```

and

**`/foo/bar/second.sh`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

source $(dirname "$0")/first.sh

func1 World
```

then

```
cd /foo
./bar/second.sh
```

prints

```
Hello World
```

### How it works

- `$0` returns relative or absolute path to the executed script
- `dirname` returns relative path to directory, where the $0 script exists
- `$( dirname "$0" )` the `dirname "$0"` command returns relative
  path to directory of executed script, which is then used as argument for `source` command
- in "second.sh", `/first.sh` just appends the name of imported shell script
- `source` loads content of specified file into current
  shell

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it worked as described!

Comment: `$(dirname "$0")` catches the problem, that `second.sh` could contain spaces in its name. But it does not work, if the **path** contains spaces, e.g. `/foo bar/second.sh`. You should use `source "$(dirname "$0")/first.sh"` instead.

Answer (score 6):

`second.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function func1() {
   fun="$1"
   book="$2"
   echo "$fun, $book\n"
}

function func2() {
   fun2="$1"
   book2="$2"
   printf "$fun2, $book2\n"
}
```

`first.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source /absolute_path_to/second.sh
func1 love horror
func2 ball mystery
```

#### You need to keep these things in your mind before using it

- Keyword `source` and `.` (a period) are the same command.
- If the `FILENAME` is not a full path to a file, the command will search for the file in the directories specified in the `$PATH` environmental variable . If the file is not found in the `$PATH`, the command will look for the file in the current directory.
- If any `ARGUMENTS` are given, they will become positional parameters to the `FILENAME`.
- If the `FILENAME` exists, the source command exit code is `0`, otherwise, if the file is not found it will return `1`.

Among these points the point to be focused on is the `second` one, you actually need to provide a `ABSOLUTE_PATH` to the file if you are using `#!/bin/bash`, `RELATIVE_PATH` just doesn't work if that is the case with you then my friend you just need to change the path to `ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old post, I am aware. However I found I could not source another file even though it was in the same directory.

```
line 3: ./functions.bash: No such file or directory
```

Then I remembered I already have in place a method for this exact situation because I import from an ini file. So here is my solution that allows me to run a program from anywhere (and apparently source files) without hardcoding the paths.

```
app="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd)"
source $app/functions.bash
```

I cannot take credit for this, its been a while and I can't recall where I got the line from otherwise I would credit them, but that's all I use to source files.

Comment: Probably from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-can-i-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itsel

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
    #!/bin/bash
        fun1(){
          echo "Fun1 from file1 $1"
        }
fun1 Hello
. file2 
fun1 Hello
exit 0
```

in file1(chmod 750 file1)
and file2

```
   fun1(){
      echo "Fun1 from file2 $1"
    }
    fun2(){
      echo "Fun1 from file1 $1"
    }
```

and run ./file2 you'll get 
Fun1 from file1 Hello
Fun1 from file2 Hello
Surprise!!! You overwrite fun1 in file1 with fun1 from file2... So as not to do so you  must

```
declare -f pr_fun1=$fun1
. file2
unset -f fun1
fun1=$pr_fun1
unset -f pr_fun1
fun1 Hello
```

it's save your previous definition for fun1 and restore it with the previous name deleting not needed imported one.
Every time you import functions from another file you may remember two aspects:

1. you may overwrite existing ones with the same names(if that the thing you want you must preserve them as described above)
2. import all content of import file(functions and global variables too)
   Be careful!  It's dangerous procedure

Answer (score -7):

```
#vi function.sh

#!/bin/bash
f1() {
    echo "Hello $name"
}

f2() {
    echo "Enter your name: "
    read name
    f1
}
f2

#sh function.sh
```

Here function `f2` will call function `f1`