# source command not found in sh shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a script that uses `sh` shell. I get an error in the line that uses the `source` command. It seems `source` is not included in my `sh` shell.

If I explicitly try to run `source` from shell I get:

```
sh: 1: source: not found
```

Should I somehow install "source"? Do I have a wrong version of `sh`?

Comment: One could reasonably argue that a shell which supports `source` is a "wrong version".

Comment: Also, the error message `source: not found` means that the `source` command was evaluated properly, but the file it should have read does not exist.

Comment: It's not possible to "install" `source` *because* it is a feature of the shell. It cannot be implemented as an external command.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is usually some other shell trying to mimic The Shell. Many distributions use `/bin/bash` for `sh`, it supports `source`. On Ubuntu, though, `/bin/dash` is used which does not support `source`. Most shells use `.` instead of `source`. If you cannot edit the script, try to change the shell which runs it.

Comment: Thanks! Replacing /bin/sh with /bin/bash did work on Ubuntu! I'm curious why though, does it mean on Ubuntu bash is sh?

Comment: @Milad: On recent Ubuntus, `/bin/sh` calls `/bin/dash`. Traditionally, `/bin/sh` called `/bin/bash` is sh-compatibility mode.

Comment: @Milad I think it does not work on ubuntu 14.04. What is your OS version?

Comment: Maybe help known - if you have cascade scripts then rename all "sh -> bash". Thank you. :-)

Comment: It wasn't immediately intuitive to me how to fix this issue unfortunately but it set me on the right path. I had to add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to the top of my Makefile.

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl I have been facing similiar issue as above question. My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036063/raspberry-pi-4-to-a-remote-mysql-stderr-bin-sh-1-mysql-not-found. You suggested adding something to the makefile? Does it mean to the `.js` script header? How I can include this `SHELL := /bin/bash` in the `.js` file header? Presently it is throwing error and I cannot include it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you help me to solve a similar question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036063/raspberry-pi-4-to-a-remote-mysql-stderr-bin-sh-1-mysql-not-found

Answer (score 242):

In Bourne shell(sh), use the . command to source a file

```
. filename
```

In certain OS's/environments (Mac OS, Travis-CI, Ubuntu, at least) this must be:

```
. ./filename
```

(Credit to [Adrien Joly's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell/13702876#comment78470475_13702462))

Comment: I am not really allowed to change the script, it runs fine on a redhat server. But on that server, source seems to be included in sh

Comment: If it has `source` it is not strictly `sh`.

Comment: I had this type of problem on Jenkins (trying to source a file stored as "secret file") and sourcing by "." command was the solution.

Comment: This should be the top answer as it will work with sh, dash, and bash.

Comment: For compatibility with Mac OS (dev environment) and Travis-CI (testing environment), I had to use `. ./filename`. Otherwise, I would get a `sh: 1: .: filename: not found` error when running tests on Travis-CI.

Comment: @AdrienJoly- I had the same issue too. Any idea _why_ that happens?

Comment: Thank you that worked on ubuntu 20.04. While I had to run shell script in npm command

Comment: Thanks!! perfectly worked for ubuntu docker

Comment: executing enviroment file works only for current execution time but is not persistent like as source command.

Comment: So simple, thanks! This should be the recommended syntax as it works across all systems, even those which support excluding "./"

Comment: _grumble_ re: the "Bourne shell(sh)"; there's been no Bourne distributed in a current-version OS since Solaris was discontinued in the mid-2000s -- ash, dash, &c are 90s-era POSIX sh, not 70s-era Bourne sh. (Back in the 90s when Bourne was legitimately still floating around, the way autotools used to distinguish between the two was running `echo ^ cat` -- if `^` worked as a pipe character, you had legacy Bourne, whereas if `^` was treated as an argument to `echo` you had POSIX sh).

Answer (score 70):

```
$ls -l `which sh`
/bin/sh -> dash

$sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash #Select "no" when you're asked
[...]

$ls -l `which sh`
/bin/sh -> bash
```

Then it will be OK

Comment: Nice! I am running RHEL and Ubuntu servers and I always have small issues such as this one with Ubuntu. I really like RHEL and RHEL like linux.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work on Ubuntu 14, this one does!

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - what does it do? `dpkg-reconfigure` might not be accessible for all users, especially on systems that are not based on Debian

Comment: Fixed my `source: not found` errors with old telnet clients after debian upgrade, thanks.

Answer (score 54):

The `source` builtin is a bashism. Write this simply as `.` instead.

**e.g.**

```
. $FILE

# OR you may need to use a relative path (such as in an `npm` script):

. ./$FILE
```

> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#source

Answer (score 17):

This problem happens because jenkins Execute Shell runs the script via its /bin/sh

Consequently, /bin/sh does not know "source"

You just need to add the below line at the top of your Execute Shell in jenkins

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: The given question is not related to Jenkins after all

Answer (score 13):

I faced this error while i was trying to call **source** command from #Jenkins execute shell.

`source profile.txt`
          or 
  `source profile.properties`

Replacement for **source** command is to use,

`. ./profile.txt` 
       or 
`. ./profile.properties`

**Note:** There is a space between the two dots(.)

Answer (score 9):

The `source` command is built into some shells. If you have a script, it should specify what shell to use on the first line, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Well, it says #!/bin/sh and on another linux if I manually enter sh and ask "which source" it tells me: source: shell built-in command

Comment: oh so this is what this line was for. I always wondered. huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**source** is a bash built-in command so to execute source command, you can log in as Root.

`sudo -s
source ./filename.sh`

Comment: This does not look like a valid solution. What if the user does not have sudo permissions? And the sourced stuff is afterwards only available as admin user, which will cause new trouble

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, switch from pure shell to bash which enables the bash features including source.
https://superuser.com/questions/1220159/bash-prompt-variables-not-working/1764353#1764353

Or use . instead of source with this form

> . ~/.your_file_name

for example

> . ~/.bashrc

please consider one space between Dot and Tilda. Tilda refers to the home directory, if your file is located somewhere above the home, use an absolute address from /

Answer (score 1):

In case you cannot change the script to use "." instead of "source", change the link of "sh" to point to "bash" instead of "dash":

```
# which sh
/usr/bin/sh

# which bash
/usr/bin/bash

# ls -la /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct  5 15:55 /usr/bin/sh -> dash

# ln -sf /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/sh

# ls -la /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb  6 09:18 /usr/bin/sh -> bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in a gnu Makefile on Ubuntu,  (where /bin/sh -> bash)

I needed to use the . command, as well as specify the target script with a ./ prefix (see example below)

source did not work in this instance, not sure why since it should be calling /bin/bash..

My SHELL environment variable is also set to /bin/bash

```
test:
    $(shell . ./my_script)
```

Note this sample does not include the tab character; had to format for stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, instead of using sh scriptname.sh to run the file, I've used . scriptname.sh and it worked!
The first line of my file contains:
`#!/bin/bash`

use this command to run the script

```
.name_of_script.sh
```

Comment: This has already been answered multiple times. Please provide more information if you add a new answer in such a case

Answer (score -3):

This may help you, I was getting this error because I was trying to reload my `.profile` with the command `. .profile` and it had a syntax error

Answer (score -10):

Bourne shell (sh) uses PATH to locate  in `source <file>`. If the file you are trying to source is not in your path, you get the error 'file not found'.

Try:

```
source ./<filename>
```

Comment: The post says `sh: 1: source: not found` not `file not found`