# Creating upstart script on centos 6 for flask

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, centos6, upstart

I am trying to create a upstart script for my flask application. I am using uWSGI to run it. 
My application resides in /home/user/apps/myapp. It contains virtual environment in venv.
My goal is to activate the virtual environment and exect ini script there

```
#description "Starts my app" 
#author "Me <myself@gmail.com>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]



script
        cd /home/user/apps/myapp
        source venv/bin/activate
        exec uwsgi --ini myapp.ini
end script
```

When i run the command sudo start myapp in /etc/init/. I got errors like  process terminated with status 127. This means that my command is unkownn. I am new to upstart scripts. What am i doing wrong, these scripts work fine in shell.

Answer (score 0):

The `source` command is not a standard shell command.  [Whatever Upstart is using internally doesn't use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13702425)  Use the dot operator instead: `. file`.

However, you don't need either of the commands before `uwsgi`, the working directory and virtualenv are both configurable in uWSGI.  It is better to let uWSGI handle the virtualenv, `source activate` is only meant as a convenience during development.

`myapp.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
virtualenv = /path/to/env
chdir = /path/to/project
# other config here
```