# Ubuntu 16.04: -sh: source: not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I updated my `.bashrc`. After that, when I tried `source ~/.bashrc` to make it works, I got:

```
-sh: 13: source: not found
```

I have reviewed the suggestions on [source command not found in sh shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell). But I still don't understand how to solve my problem.

If I use `. ~/.bashrc` alternatively, I will get:

```
-sh: 16: /home/user_1/.bashrc: shopt: not found
-sh: 24: /home/user_1/.bashrc: shopt: not found
-sh: 111: /home/user_1/.bashrc: shopt: not found
-sh: 29: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: [[: not found
-sh: 35: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: [[: not found
-sh: 51: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: shopt: not found
-sh: 57: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 62: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 65: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 68: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 71: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 74: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 77: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 80: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 83: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 86: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 89: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 92: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-sh: 101: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

This is the `.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export MPIHOME=/home/user_2/local/openmpi-4.0.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MPIHOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$MPIHOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: You are running posix shell `sh` when you are doing `source ~/.bashrc`. Run bash.

Comment: In your interactive terminal, type `bash` and press enter. Then try to source your rc-file. If that works, change your default shell to bash using `chsh`.

Comment: @Joxixi : Adding to the (correct) comment by KamilCuk: You can easily see from the error message that the error was not generated by bash, because bash prefixes its error messages with the string _bash:_.

Comment: @Socowi, thanks for your suggestions. I tried to use ```chsh -s /bin/bash user_1``` in order to change my default shell, but I got ```You may not change the shell for 'user_1'.``` I am a normal user,  but I think I can change the login shell for my own account. But I can't...