# source. env command does not work when called from package.json scripts in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, yarnpkg

I have the following entry for the scripts key/property in my package.json

```
"stop": "source .env && yarn doc:stop && lsof -t -i tcp:$EXPRESS_PORT | xargs kill 2> /dev/null && pgrep -f $(pwd) | xargs kill 2> /dev/null",
```

It does not work when I execute

```
yarn stop
```

It throws the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

But I can call execute directly from the Ubuntu command terminal with no error

```
source .env
```

I get the same error when using . (dot) instead of source.

```
/bin/sh: 1: .: .env: not found
```

How can I fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like using `. .env` would work
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089609/5155484 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#source

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two alternatives:

1. At your stop script definition use bash:

`"stop" : "bash -ac ' LOCATION="."; source .env; echo $REACT_APP_ENV; unset IFS' && ...etc"`

2. Add export at your `.env`, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs)

The third and final alternative is that your file is not realy there, you can verify using `ls -la | grep .env`

Comment: I am sure the file exists. I tested your option 1 but it did not work.

Comment: @JuanPabloFernandez I got, I have an example using cat and cypress, could you try? ```"cy:open": "export $(cat .env | xargs) && CYPRESS_CLIENT=${REACT_APP_KC_ENV} npx cypress open",```

Comment: I got the following output
yarn run v1.21.1
$ export $(cat .env | xargs) && CYPRESS_CLIENT=${REACT_APP_KC_ENV} npx cypress open
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
/bin/sh: 1: export: #: bad variable name
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.