# How to use a shell script to start python script on boot up within an Python environment?

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi, launcher

how would I run python script on startup (on Raspberrypi 4B, Raspi_os 64bit) within an python(3.9) environment?

I tried to just add
`source envname/bin/activate` to `launcher.sh`

my launcher file looks like this:

```
cd /home/pi/thefolder
PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-package
source envname/bin/activate
pyhton3 /home/pi/thefolder/run.py
```

Apparently the python3 command is not run in the env as I get an `ModuleNotFoundError` for Pandas. Which is installed in the env.

EDIT1:

if I just create a new shell script with only

```
source envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

running after chmod with sh test.sh I get the return

```
> test.sh 1: source: not found 
> Hi Stackoverflow
```

while I can activate the env in the terminal

EDIT2:

Apparently Ubuntu bin/dash ist used and not bin/sh. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702425/source-command-not-found-in-sh-shell) is post about it

Now I have to checkout how to change it

Edit3:
using :

```
. envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

instead of

```
source envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

seems to work. Testing in progress

---**Final Edit:**---

**Yes it works.** But important, it apparently has to be in the first line otherwise the `file envname cannot be found`

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
. envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

instead of

```
source envname/bin/activate
echo Hi Stackoverflow
```

Works. As Ubuntu uses /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh

Apparently the `. envname/bin/activate` has to be the first command