# Execute Shell file functions in Mac

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have the following shell file that contains this:

```
sh
nightlyTag() {
    echo $1-alpha.$(date +%Y%m%d).$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
}

yarnPubCanaryVersion() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo "No version argument supplied, maybe you meant v1.0.0?"
        return 1
    fi
    version=`nightlyTag $1`
    yarn version --new-version $version --no-git-tag-version
    npm publish --tag canary
    git reset --hard HEAD
}
```

I make the file executable with `chmod +x canary.sh`, then I run it doing `./canary.sh`  then my terminal changes to `sh-3.2$` then I try to run the functions in the terminal like this `nightlyTag` and I get

> sh: nightlyTag: command not found

Same for `yarnPubCanaryVersion`.

I was looking at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822790/can-i-call-a-function-of-a-shell-script-from-another-shell-script)

Comment: You use as first command `sh`. I don't know why you do it, but at this point the functions are not defined yet, because their definition comes **after** the sh command. So, at least, the `sh` would have to be the last command.  But if you like `sh` as a shell so much, why don't you make it your login shell, and **source** the function definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to run functions from the terminal after you run the script.

You need to source the script to do this:

```
source ./canary.sh
```

Or add the contents of the file to the .bashrc file or its equivalent, and then source it.

The source command is used to load any function file into the current shell.

Now once you call those functions you will get the expected output.

At the top of your sh file you need to include:

```
#! /path/to/bash
```

the path to the bash that you are using.

Comment: That didn't work. I get the same results as doing ./canary.sh I feel it has to be related to this https://thorsten-hans.com/5-types-of-zsh-aliases#functions-for-aliases-with-parameters

Comment: Yes, I am not sure about the Mac system but your terminal should still have a .bashrc file. Inside it you can directly post the contents of your .sh file, and then once you source it it will work.

Comment: @devpato at the top of your sh file you need to include: #! /usr/bin/bash

Or the path to the bash that you are using.

Comment: @devpato I am happy that I could help.